# How to import only one specific compiled .class into a java project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a .class file, which was taken from another library. I, however don't want to include the entire library into the project. So I decided to pull this one specific class out of the .jar archive, luckily it doesn't import anything else from the library itself so it can be used on its own. Then I've created a new package inside my project, of exactly the same name as it was in the original library (com.blahblah.library), and put the class there. When I import the class from my code however, no matter what I do, it always says "can't resolve symbol X". What to do now?

Comment: Create a new jar file with just your single class file in it, with same full name as it had in the original jar file.

Comment: can you post the hole class code , and your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

You could create a jar and add the jar as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the `.class` file in the source root, it will not work.

You need to create a new directory corresponding to the class package name and add the parent directory as a library (`foo.bar.MyClass`):

```
lib\
   foo\
       bar\
           MyClass.class
```

Configuring the `lib` directory as a library and adding this library to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) should help.